# Using the $.post with JQuery for two forms on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello I am wondering if this is possible?  Having two different forms on the same page using the jquery post to send it php to do some checking. The first from works flawlessly, however when I go to the second form I get an error saying it is an undefined variable but I am using the exact same method I used for the first form.  It will load anything echoed in the php page for the feed form but will not echo back what I am typing in.  Is there a better, more correct way to do it?

This is not for a real site, just testing for a project I am working on.

HTML:

```
<form action="php/signup.php" method="post" class="form-inline" name="signupForm">
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="username" id="user_in">
    <input type="password" maxtlength="20" name="password" id="pass_in">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Sign Up">
</form>
<div id="feedback"></div> <!-- Feedback for Sign Up Form -->
    <br /><br />
<form name="feedForm">
    <input type="text" id="feed_in" name="feed_me_in" placeholder="feed">
    <div id="feedme"></div> <!-- FEEDback for feed form -->
</form>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#feedback').load('php/signup.php').show();
        //SIGN IN FORM
        $('#user_in, #pass_in').keyup(function() {
            $.post('php/signup.php', { username: document.signupForm.username.value,
                                       password: document.signupForm.password.value }, 
                function(result) {
                    $('#feedback').html(result).show
                });
         });

         $('#feedme').load('php/feed.php').show();
         //FEED FORM
         $('#feed_in').keyup(function() {
             $.post('php/feed.php', { feed: document.feedForm.feed_me_in.value },
                  function(result) {
                      $('$feedme').html(result).show
                   });
          });
    });
</script>
```

PHP for Feed Form:

```
<?php
     $feed = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feed']);
     if(isset($feed)) {
         echo $feed;
     } else {}
?>
```

PHP for the Sign Up Form:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        include_once('connect.php'); //Connect
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

        $sql1 = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $check = mysql_query($sql1);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
        if(strlen($username)<=4) {
            echo "Username is too short";
        } elseif($numrows == 0) {
            echo "Username is available";
        } elseif($numrows > 0) {
            echo "Username is already taken";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please type a username";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `show` is a function (x2), and `$feedme` should be `#feedme`. Fix those three issues and see what happens.

Comment: Doesn't using <input type="submit" /> automatically cause a page refresh.  If I am not wrong then the question I have is if your using jquery ajax post functionality wouldn't you then not want to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('$feedme').html(result).show
```

should be

```
$('#feedme').html(result).show();
```